# apache SSLEngine On, in separate Vhost, or mix with :80?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm unsure if I should create a separate Vhost in apache for HTTPS purposes. I need to pass the "SSLEngine" option and I'm wondering if that would hurt performance on normal http-requests? Does it matter if I use SSLEngine On inside a *:80 Vhost, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName *.domain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /current-certificate
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /current-key
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that block you are running SSL on 80 and 443, prob not what you want. You need a separate vhost entry. One for regular http and the other for SSL.

And yes it would degrade performance. But check out SSL persistent connections. Most of the SSL overhead is from the handshake not the actual transfer.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Can we set up persistent SSL connections in Apache?

Comment: @Jorre: They're enabled by default; the [default timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) is 15 seconds.